# EF4 Linq return type generic list

Tags: collections, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a C#-4 MVC3 RC test-application which is using Entity Framework 4.

I have this method:

```
public static List<Content> FetchMenu(int websiteID) {
    return (from w in ContextHelper.Current.Websites
            where w.WebsiteID == websiteID
            select w.Contents).ToList();
}
```

The objects involved here (Content and Website) are of type EntityObject.

The above function gives compilation error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.List<Manager.Models.Content>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Manager.Models.Content>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

w.Contents is an `EntityCollection<Content>` type collection.

How do I defer the Linq.IQueryable type to return a generic List of type Content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use parentheses, so that you apply `ToList()` to the whole query (an object of type `IQueryable`):

```
public static List<Content> FetchMenu(int websiteID) {
    return (from w in ContextHelper.Current.Websites
            where w.WebsiteID == websiteID
            select w.Contents).ToList();
}
```

Otherwise you are calling `ToList()` on `w.Contents` only and the `select` is applied afterwards. It might be clearer if I show the method chaining syntax.

Your version:

```
ContextHelper.
           Current.
           Websites.
           Where(w => w.WebsiteID == websiteID).
           Select(w => w.Contents.ToList());
```

Correct version:

```
ContextHelper.
           Current.
           Websites.
           Where(w => w.WebsiteID == websiteID).
           Select(w => w.Contents).
           ToList();
```

**Edit**:

Since `w.Contents` is a collection, you need to flatten it out by using `SelectMany`:

```
public static List<Content> FetchMenu(int websiteID) {
    return ContextHelper.
           Current.
           Websites.
           Where(w => w.WebsiteID == websiteID).
           SelectMany(w => w.Contents).
           ToList();
}
```

Comment: I indeed forgot the parenthesis, but it still gives another conversion error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Manager.Models.Content>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Manager.Models.Content>'

Answer (score 0):

```
    var query = (from w in ContextHelper.Current.Websites
                 where w.WebsiteID == websiteID
                 select w.Contents).First();

    return query.ToList();
```

The .First() seems to do the trick... thanks.

Comment: By using first, you will only be selecting one item from every `Contents` collection (for every website). To get all the items, use `SelectMany`. See my updated post.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but .First() also selects all items. I think it means it will select the first collection, which contains all content items.

Answer (score 0):

[Yakimych's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235295/ef4-linq-return-type-generic-list/4235331#4235331) using `SelectMany()` is corret. For completeness, here it is using "query comprehension" syntax:

```
public static List<Content> FetchMenu(int websiteID) {
    return (from w in ContextHelper.Current.Websites
            where w.WebsiteID == websiteID
            from c in w.Contents
            select c).ToList();
}
```